# What's the size limitation of a message when PUB/SUB in Redis channel

Tags: python, redis, publish-subscribe

I am currently implementing redis PUB/SUB in one of my project, and it raises a concern to me, what's the size limitation of a message when PUB/SUB in Redis channel. Was the limit equal to the available memory of the computer? or there will be a threshold in somewhere of config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Subsequent to my original answer below, I came across the actual answer. There is a configuration parameter in `redis.conf` called:

```
client-output-buffer-limit
```

You can check it with:

```
config get client-output-buffer-limit
"normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 33554432 8388608 60"
```

The 33554432 after `pub/sub` is the maximum buffer size for pub/sub clients, and the 8388608 is a soft limit that may not be exceeded for more than 60 seconds.

So, my answer below changes if you raise the limit using a command like the following:

```
config set client-output-buffer-limit "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 53554432 8388608 60"
```

I have not done any tests as to whether this is advisable, or safe or even sensible but think it is materially relevant to the answer.

**Original Answer**

I don't know where the limit arises, but just FYI, I did some simple tests with the `redis-cli` client, subscribing like this:

```
redis-cli SUBSCRIBE myStream
```

And I sent data, in multiples of 1MB like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=$((1024*1024)) count=20  | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myStream
```

So, the command above worked, at 20MB but the following command for 21MB failed:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=$((1024*1024)) count=21  | redis-cli -x PUBLISH myStream
```

and the subscriber was disconnected with the message:

```
Error: Server closed the connection
```

I'm calling this an *"empirical"* answer.

Comment: This is really useful, thank you @Mark !!

Comment: Note: the command is `CONFIG GET client-output-buffer-limit`

there's a dash between `buffer` and `limit`

Answer (score 3):

Just for your information, I experimented myself, the approximate ceiling size is around 21MB to 22MB on my machine (Debian 5.4.8-1) (it may vary depends on the OS and redis version), it will cause a redis ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to set values via the CLI

```
    CONFIG SET client-output-buffer-limit "pubsub 256MB 64MB 1"
```

Or via a config file:

```
    client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32MB 8MB 60
```

The syntax of every client-output-buffer-limit directive is the following:

`client-output-buffer-limit <class> <hard limit> <soft limit> <soft seconds>`

A client is immediately disconnected once the hard limit is reached, or if the soft limit is reached and remains reached for the specified number of seconds (continuously).

So for instance if the hard limit is 32 megabytes and the soft limit is 16 megabytes / 10 seconds, the client will get disconnected immediately if the size of the output buffers reach 32 megabytes, but will also get disconnected if the client reaches 16 megabytes and continuously overcomes the limit for 10 seconds.

By default normal clients are not limited because they don't receive data without asking (in a push way), but just after a request, so only asynchronous clients may create a scenario where data is requested faster than it can read.